# VBA - Updating Master file from new file

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I have a Master file which monitors shipment progress for my company. I update this on a weekly basis with progress on existing shipments (shipments which are already in the master file) and input new shipments. These updates come in the form of a update sheet which is in the same format as the master file. I have automated the input of new shipments, but I am stuck on how I could update the existing shipments progress.

Currently I perform a vlookup manually based off a shipment reference number. This is a pain because there are multiple shipment progress columns and I have to trawl through each new input to remove the vlookup formula.

FOR EXAMPlE: shipment reference is in column "C", shipment pickup is in column "AG", shipment dispatched is in column "AH" and  shipment arrived is in column "AI".. and so on. In the master sheet I might have the reference number and pickup date. The update sheet might have the dispatch date for this shipment. I would want to take the dispatch date and copy it into the master file for this shipment.

I essentially want to search for blanks in each column of the master file and copy this data from the update file based on the shipment reference. I cannot copy and past over the master file data because I have added a lot of data manually the previous week which the updated file may not have or agree with.

Thank you for your help

Please see my attempted code:

```
Sub Eupdatedates()
Dim lr As Long, rw As Long, extRNG As Range
Set wb = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("RawDATA")
lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


Set extRNG = Workbooks("updatefile.csv").Worksheets("report").Range("C:AL")


For i = 33 To 38 ' columns which contain dates that need updating


    ws.Range("$A$2:$CV$" & lastRow).AutoFilter field:=i, Criteria1:="=" 'filter out cells containing data



    lastRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row ' find last row after filtering
    firstRow = Range("Cells(2,i): Column(i)" &        Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row ' indentify first row after filtering
    For rw = firstRow To lastRow ' loop through each each empty row cell and perform a vlookup to the update file
        Cells(rw, i) = Application.VLookup(Cells(rw, i), extRNG, i - 2,  False)
    Next rw

Next i



End Sub
```

I am getting the error with "Range("Cells(2,i): Column(i)" I think I have looked online and cannot seem to find a way to define the range within a for loop. I am new to VBA so a lot of ground to make up. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Have you attempted to write VBA code to resolve this?

Comment: No, I am unsure where to start and what would be an efficient method. Thanks

Comment: Well, start your job dividing the main task into small tasks - e.g. 1. search for blanks per columns, 2. find a way to copy and paste over the master file, 3. etc. Then make a small research for each task and show what you got.

Comment: I was unsure if there was a quick fix for this problem, but I have now edited in my attempted code looping through each column cell individually.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for VBA. I have done something similar in the past and used VBA to complete the task but it's not something I could code without having the workbooks in front of me. As a pointer I usually start with a big sheet of blank paper and write out the process in logical steps before beginning to code, e.g.

- How many rows are there? (I want to know when to stop)
- Where is the update sheet and what is it called?
- start with first row (row number = 1)
- What is the shipment reference (ship ref)?
- select cell (row number, column of interest number)
- is it blank? YES - find corresponding value in update sheet based on ship ref and update, NO - move to next column of interest
- No more columns of interest for this row? - move to next row (row number +1)
- etc.

Comment: Thank you Kyle, This is what I was looking for as I was not sure if there was a two liner answer. The number of rows will vary, and I will keep the work files open while I perform the macro. I have edited the post with my attempted code where I am stuck at one point. Thanks

Comment: Glad to be of some help. With your error message - check where your quotes are in Range("Cells(2,i): Cells(lastRow,i)" . It may be more efficient to build your range string outside of the brackets, something like: | For i = 2 To 4 | stRange = "$A$2:B" & CStr(i) | firstRow = Range(stRange) |Sorry, can't get line breaks to work in this reply so have added | where they should be. –

Comment: you lost me a bit there Kyle!! I have changed the code to do the following though it is still not working.  Now when I run the code it simple does nothing. 


Sub ESourcedate()¦
Set extRNG =¦ Workbooks("updatefile.csv").Worksheets("report").Range("C:AL")¦
Set wb = Workbooks("masterfile.xlsm")¦
Set ws = wb.Sheets("RawDATA")¦
lastrow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row¦
For i = 33 To 38¦
For r = 3 To lastrow¦
If Cells(r, i).Value = " " Then¦
Cells(r, i).Value = Application.VLookup(Cells(r, 3), extRNG, i - 2, False)¦
End If¦
Next r¦
Next i¦
End Sub¦

Comment: ¦ indicates line breaks

Comment: Hi SmC. My message above was highlighting the position of the quotes in that piece of code, one inside the parentheses and one outside. I would not use vlookup in VBA (not even sure you can), I would simply set the text in the target cell to that in the source cell. 

You'll need to continually switch between sheets for each cell unless you:
- Activate the source sheet
- load all the source sheet values for the row in question into variables 
- Activate the target spreadsheet
- Check for empty values and update from your variables
- .move next
- etc...